# How to find sum of lines and words

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have three files with each one containing one row with two columns as follows:

**file1.txt**

3    5

**file2.txt**

2    6

**file3.txt**

6    3

I want to combine them in a single file that sums the first columns and the seconds columns each as follows:

**finalfile.txt**

11    14

I need to do that with Unix commands

Comment: What is python doing in your tags if you require Unix commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the Python tag was a mistake, this will do the trick.

```
echo `cat file*.txt` | awk 'BEGIN {a=0;b=0;} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ( i%2 == 0 ) { b+=$i } else { a+=$i } } } END { print a, b }'
```

The echo `...` puts all the numbers on a single line. The awk program sums the odd and even columns in variables a and b.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a quick way using `awk`:

```
awk '{ one+=$1; two+=$2 } END { print one, two }' file[1-3].txt > finalfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to try the problem yourself before asking for help. However I find interesting the problem. Here is a possible solutions with a bash script:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > treefiles.txt
suma=0;
sumb=0;

while read a b
do
  suma=$((suma + a));
  sumb=$((sumb + b));
done < treefiles.txt;

echo "$suma $sumb";
```

Taking in account the comments:

```
suma=0;
sumb=0;

while read a b
do
  ((suma += a));
  ((sumb += b));
done < <(cat f1.txt f2.txt f3.txt)

echo "$suma $sumb";
```

Comment: I like that file reading technique: while read ... < file.
I hadn't seen that until I started trawling SO.

Comment: I think the temp file can be avoided, by using redirect as `<(cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt)`.

Comment: @anishsane, make sure you're redirecting from that process substitution: `done < <(cat file*.txt)`

Comment: @Rafael, you can put the assignment inside the arithmetic expression: `((suma += a))`